# Unity crashes in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, 20.04, crash

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop and it randomly crashes on closing the random window. Happened to me multiple times today after i was removing bloatware from system. I didn't removed anything that should affect DE. It happens completely randomly after closing windows like terminal with exit or Firefox with arrow box. After this freeze i am still able to get to tty. System still works but whole DE freezes and after a minute completely crashes. It restarts itself and runs fine until the next crash.
Bloat that I was removing and processes i was disabling

`sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center` - No longer needed in Unity

`sudo apt-get remove gnome-software` - I don't use gnome software center

```
sudo apt remove gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

`sudo apt remove --purge snapd` - I don't use snaps

```
sudo apt-get remove avahi-daemon
```

`sudo mv /usr/lib/evolution-data-server /usr/lib/evolution-data-server-disabled` - This is not removed just "disabled"

`sudo apt-get remove nemo*` - I dont use nemo and nemo-desktop was contantly consuming my RAM

I see no way that this could harm my DE and make it unstable... It was completely fine before removing these.

Comment: Ubuntu does not use use Unity anymore. How did you replace Gnome3 with Unity?

Comment: I get that crash too, using Gnome.